# How do I undo a revert in Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I just started using git, I've been working on a large project. I made an initial commit and didn't commit again for a while. My project is almost done so I decided to mess around with git again and commit the new files in my project, which I did, but didn't push. I read right after that that it's preferred to make small commits, so I decided to delete my last commit and practice making smaller commits from my project. I used git revert  and it deleted most of my files!! I read online to 'revert the revert' and used git revert . It said failed to commit and that I needed to commit changes in my project, so I did and tried again making sure to include the correct commit, it failed. I'm semi-panicking, I was almost done and that was a lot of work (for me).

Edit:
Here's the git log:

```
commit 286f067d7ff46385af05381cfe1b657e60204393 (HEAD -> master)
Author: my username <my email

Date:   Thu Jun 30 19:18:45 2022 -0400

trying to fix this

commit 27dd527567348acecc31cbababa9ddc2a31eacdc
Author: my username <my email>
Date:   Thu Jun 30 16:39:31 2022 -0400

reverted commit
```

Comment: First: take a deep breath. If you correctly commited, then everything should still be around somewhere, even if you "wrongly" reverted afterwards. Check the output of `git log` and review the commits if they seem relevant.

Comment: If you can find the SHA hash of the reverted commit, you should be able to `git cherry-pick <hash>`.

Comment: sorry, I have sha hash of the original commit before reverting, and the sha hash or the reverted commit

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way (the cleanest possible) to revert a commit is to use `git reset`

Basically, these are the steps I follow:

1. Get the commit code to revert to
2. `git reset --hard <code>` to return to that commit
3. Backup the entire project somewhere else in the computer
4. `git pull` to return to the latest commit
5. Erase everything and paste the previous backup
6. `git add .`
7. `git commit`
8. `git push`

I know it may take some time meanwhile some codes do this automatically, but I think it's the safest way